# isomorphism of $Q[x]/(x^2-3x + 2)$ and the ring, former by pairs $(a,b)$ with component addition and multiplication

Tags: abstract-algebra

How can i prove that the ring $Q[x]/(x^2 - 3x + 2)$ is isomorphic to ring, formed by pairs $(a,b)$ $(a,b \in Q)$ with component addition and multiplication? Thanks.

Comment: "...is isomorphic to ring..." **What** ring? Pairs of *what*?

Answer (score 5):

Chinese remainder theorem: $$\mathbb{Q}[X] / (X^2 - 3X + 2) \cong \mathbb{Q}[X] / (X - 2) \times \mathbb{Q}[X] / (X - 1)$$ and each factor is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$, via the evaluations $X \mapsto 2$ and $X \mapsto 1$ respectively.

Comment: @dan At the least, it's an idea - the details should be easy enough to fill in.

Comment: @dan That $\varphi$ is a homomorphism winds up being because $(f \cdot g)(1) = f(1) \cdot g(1)$ and $(f+g)(1) = f(1) + g(1)$, for any $f,g \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$. Mind that you should be proving $(a,b) + (c,d) = (a+c,b+d)$ and $(a,b) \cdot (c,d) = (ac,bd)$ and not as you've written.